# Using drag and drop in jquery, cannot get the right answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my first time  posting so apologies if I've missed anything.
What Im trying to do is randomise an array of strings and then get the user to drop them in the correct boxes. I have the randomisation done but I can't work out the code that allows the user to drop it in the right place. I can either get it that they can drop in any box or none at all
Im not a programmer, this is part of a final thesis on learning so Im trying to keep it simple
here is my script. Thanks in advance:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() {

  // Hide the success message
  $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );

  // Reset the game
  correctCards = 0;
  $('#wordPile').html( '' );
  $('#cardSlots').html( '' );

  // Create the pile of shuffled words
  var newwords = [ 'me', 'you', 'him', 'her','it','them', 'those', 'test', 'apple', 'orange'];
  newwords.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );


  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) 
  {
    $('<div>' + newwords[i] + '</div>').data( 'right', newwords[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+newwords[i] ).appendTo( '#wordPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#wordPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the word slots
  var words = [ 'me', 'you', 'him', 'her','it','them', 'those', 'test', 'apple', 'orange'];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) 
  {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'right', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#wordPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'right' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'right' );

  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 

  // If all the words  have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if ( correctCards == 10 ) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}

</script>
```

Comment: Does it make a difference ( genuine question , not being sarky :))

Comment: Well, it's recommended to keep up to date with libraries and frameworks: bug fixes, new features, deprecated functions... 1.5 is *well behind* jQuery development.

Comment: ok thanks. It is code Im amending so it may be older than I thought

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of wrapping the code in dom ready event:

```
 $(function(){
    //script here
 });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //script here
});
```

Comment: That seems to make no difference, I maybe should be clearer, the code runs perfectly up until the point where I drag and drop.  I think the issue is in the:  .data( 'number', i ). section but can't work out the solution